# por que me da el error?

Tags: php

Esta web me da error en la linea 42 segun error_log credo desde hosting. alguien me indica como solucionar o redirigirme a un link como **http://subdominio.miweb.com** en ves de usar **header("location: http://subdominio.miweb.com/avanzado_patch.php");** dentro de la misma pestaña y 
 ventana?

```
<?php
session_start();
$host       = $_SESSION['Panel_Avanzado_IP']; 
$username   = $_SESSION['Panel_Avanzado_SQL_USER']; 
$pass       = $_SESSION['Panel_Avanzado_SQL_PASS']; 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$link = @mssql_connect($host, $username, $pass) or Die(
"
<Center>
<font color= #FF000>
Por Favor Avise a la Administraci&oacute;n de este error Copie y envie ERROR CODIGO: 235698 
</font>
<a href= 'https://dyaforzagames.com' 
vlink = #FB07E5 
alink = #F0F40B 
link  = #F9FD02>Enviar</a>
</Center>
<p><center><IMG SRC='../css/loguese_xfavor.png'></center></p>
");
?>

<?php
$Usuario     = $_POST['Usuario'];//indica la web alojada
$tipo_DB     = $_POST['tipo_DB'];//indica la web alojada
$web_host    = $_POST['web_host'];//indica la web host
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
// $_SESSION['parche_usuario']=$Usuario;
include_once "../includes/mysql_conex.php";
            IF ($tipo_DB=='cloud_data_avanzado')
            {
                // Verificar Existensia de Cuenta en Data Base PS_UserData
                $patch_avanzado1 = mysqli_query($conexion, '
                SELECT *
                FROM cloud_data_avanzado
                where Usuario = \'' . $Usuario . '\'
                ');
                if (mysqli_num_rows ($patch_avanzado1)==0)
                    die('el usuario no existeen Admin Panel Avanzado.');
                else
                {
                header("location: avanzado_patch.php");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // Verificar Existensia de Cuenta en Data Base PS_UserData
                $patch_avanzadosa = mysqli_query($conexion, '
                SELECT *
                FROM cloud_data
                where Usuario = \'' . $Usuario . '\'');
                if (mysqli_num_rows ($patch_avanzadosa)==0)
                    die('el usuario no existe Admin Panel.');
                else
                {
                header("location: basico_patch.php");
                }
            }
    // }
}
?>
<html>
        <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        input {
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
         }
    </style>    
    <title>Cambio Contrase&ntilde;a</title>
    </head>
    <font face="Trebuchet MS">
    <center><body><br /><br />
    <center><b><font color= "#FF0000">IMPORTANTE</font></b></center>
    <br>Esto solo debe Usarlo  unicamente el Due&ntilde;o  del server</br>
    <br>DYAForza no se hace responsable por cambios del server</br>
    <br></br>
    <b>Cambiar el Email en una Cuenta</b>
    <form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">
    <table WIDTH="500">
    <tr><td>Tu Usuario de Panel:</td><td><input type="text" placeholder = "Usuario AdminPanel" name="Usuario" /></td></tr>
    <!--<tr><td>Tu Contrase&ntilde;a de Staff:</td><td><input type="password" type="text" placeholder = "Clave o Usuario Staff" name="pw" /></td></tr>-->
    <tr><td>IP o Web de Parches:</td><td><input type="text" size="24" value="http://<?php echo $host ?>" placeholder="Ejemplo: http://www.shaiya.com" name="web_host"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tipò Panel Activado:</td><td><select name="tipo_DB" required/>
                        <option value="">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                        <option value="cloud_data_avanzado">Panel Avanzado</option>
                        <option value="Panel_Basico">Panel Basico</option>
                        <option value="Panel_GM_Status_16_32">Panel de GM con Status 16 32</option>
                        <option value="Panel_GS_Sin_Status">Panel GS Sin Status</option>
                        <option value="Panel_Staff_Status_48_64_80">Panel Staff Status 48 64 80</option>
    </table>
<p><input type="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cambiar Pass&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>
    </body></center>
    </html>
```

el error sale para ser mas exacto en esta linea:

**`header("location: avanzado_patch.php");`**

donde error_log indica:

**`PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dyaforza/public_html/administradores/Panel_Avanzado/patchs.php:22) in /home/dyaforza/public_html/administradores/Panel_Avanzado/patchs.php on line 42`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fallo se da porque ya se ha empezado a enviar información al cliente en la línea 42. Lo que tienes que hacer es quitar el cierre y la apertura que hay un poco más arriba. ?> ?php genera un espacio que te da ese error al enviar una cabecera