# Por que me da error session_start(); creo tambien debe estar vinculado a header?

Tags: php

verán en el link de mi anterior ([Por que me da error session_start();?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/261819/por-que-me-da-error-session-start/261878#261878)) tengo un problema con session_start(); pero según mi experiencia Son aparentemente dos cosas distintas, cosa en en otra pregunta resolvi separando

```
?> de <?php
```

Sin embargo, Ahora Comente:

```
//session_start();
```

Intente Colocar SIN EL CUERPO y fui directo osea ***localhost/index.php***, aparte de  sin cache, reiniciando la PC borrando la cache de todos mis navegadores en 8 Computadoras y sin **(contenido completo)** ni mas nada que las siguientes 3 lineas en php dentro de mi localhost:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ?>
```

y Siguio Dandome el mismo error:

***Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\indexb25b.php:65) in C:\xampp\htdocs\indexb25b.php on line 66***

Cuya Web esta Completa deberia estar asi:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<!-- Mirrored from sh-Dyne.com/?p=login by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 06 May 2019 13:57:19 GMT -->
<head>
    <title>
        Iniciar Sesión | Shaiya Dyne    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Icono de la pagina web -->
            <!-- JavaScript includes - jQuery, the complexify plugin and our own script.js -->
    <!-- OpenGraph -->
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Shaiya - Dyne" >
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" >
    <meta property="og:url" content="index.php" >
    <meta property="og:title" content="Shaiya Dyne" >
    <meta property="og:image" content="img/bg.jpg" >
    <meta property="og:description" content="Sign up for the LawDynes Beta! Join to experience the gravity-based multiplayer first person shooter that shatters the laws of physics." >
    <!-- END: OpenGraph -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/ico.png" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div class="hirez-super-nav">
    <ul class="center-nav">
        <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="index0f50.php?p=home">Inicio</a>
             </li>
        <li class="nav_menu">
        Información
            <ul class="a_menu">       
                <li><a href="index6fff.php?p=rules">Reglas</a></li>
                <li><a href="index590d.php?p=drop">Drop List</a></li>
                <li><a href="index54ab.php?p=rango">Puntos por Rango</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_menu"> Ranking
            <ul class="a_menu">
                <li><a href="indexfbb8.php?p=rank">PvP Rank</a></li>
                <li><a href="index9f35.php?p=gbr">GBR Rank</a></li>
                <li><a href="index0ea0.php?p=boss">Boss Record</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
             </li>
        <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="index7b9c.php?p=donation">Donar</a>
             </li>
            <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="https://#/forms/51TaekyGsxYBg0Em1"  target="_blank">Soporte</a>
             </li>
             <li class="download">
               <a href="indexacaf.php?p=download">Descargar</a>
             </li>
             <li class="a_ref_right">
               <a href='indexb25b.php?p=login'>Iniciar Sesión</a>
             </li>
             <li class='a_ref_right'>
               <a href='indexdb34.php?p=register'>Registrarse</a>
             </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$UserID     = $_POST['UserID'];
$Password   = $_POST['Password'];
include_once "includes/obdc_conex.php";
    if(empty($UserID))
    {
    die("<br></br><p></p><font color=red>Usuario Requerido, por favor ingrese un Usuario.</font>");
    }
        if(empty($Password))
        {
        die("<br></br><p></p><font color=red>Contrase&ntilde;a Requerida, por favor ingrese un Usuario.</font>");
        }
            $intro = "SELECT UserID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserID = '$UserID' and Pw = '$Password'";
            $intro1 = odbc_exec($dbConn,$intro);
            if(odbc_num_rows($intro1) == 0)
            {
                die("<br></br><p></p><center><font color=red size=40>El Usuario NO Existe, Intente de Nuevo Por favor.</font><center>");
            }
                else
                {
                $_SESSION['UserID']=$UserID;
                $_SESSION['Password']=$Password;
                header('location: actionx2s.php');
                }
}
?>
<div>
    <center><a href="index0f50.php?p=home"><img src="img/logo.png" border="0" width="614" height="204"></a></center>
</div> <div class="item-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-small1">
      <div class="god-container glass horizontal"><!-- 1050 para pvp ranks, 600 para gbr, boss 700-->
      <center>
 <script src="js/login.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
<style>
    table.login_table
    {
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    table.login_table tr td:nth-child(1)
    {
        width:24px;
        text-align:right;
    }

    table.login_table tr td:nth-child(2)
    {
        width:220px;
    }

    table.login_table tr td:nth-child(3)
    {
        width:24px;
        text-align:left;
    }
</style>
<h2 class="no_select">Iniciar Sesión</h2>
<div class="text_center">
    <div class="content_360 inline_block">
        <div class="content_body">
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">
              <table class="login_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input maxlength="18" class="text_center" id="UserID" name="UserID"   placeholder="Username" type="text" value="" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input maxlength="16" class="text_center" id="Password" name="Password"  placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                            <input maxlength="16" class="text_center hidden" id="PasswordText" name="PasswordText"   placeholder="Password" type="text" value="" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="toggle_password_visibility" class="del_1" tooltip="Show password" style="vertical-align:middle;"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input name ="submit" id="button_log_in" type="submit" value="Log In" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="error"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="content_hr"></div>
                            <div>
                                <div>¿No estas registrado? <a href="indexdb34.php?p=register">Registrate aquí</a>.</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
</form>        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixfooter">
<footer>
    <div class="divline divline-top"></div>        
    <div class="footer-links">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" data-i18n="[href]site.footer.links.privacy.url;site.footer.links.privacy.copy" class="btn btn-privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" data-i18n="[href]site.footer.links.terms.url;site.footer.links.terms.copy" class="btn btn-terms">Terms of Service</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divline divline-bot"></div>
    <div data-i18n="[html]site.footer.legal" class="footer-legal">
        <span>©2016 Shaiya Dyne, Inc.</span> <span>©2016 Dyne Games, Inc.</span> <span>All Rights Reserved.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="js/accordion.js"></script>
</body>

<!-- Mirrored from /?p=login by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 06 May 2019 13:57:19 GMT -->
</html>
```

Ahora el segundo problema debe estar Vinculado a el anterior del **session_start();**:

***Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\indexb25b.php:65) in C:\xampp\htdocs\indexb25b.php on line 91***

header('location: actionx2s.php');

Comment: Eso pasa cuando ya habías hecho `session_start()` en otra página y la incluíste en esta. Estoy casi seguro que aquí `includes/obdc_conex.php` tienes otro `session_start()`, si lo tienes quita el primero que declaraste hasta arriba. Debería funcionar

Comment: Jajaj estoy seguro que estas en lo cierto.

Comment: Eso ocurre porque hay alguna linea antes del session_start o de la apertura del <?php. Aparte no es un error sino un warning.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

Comment: pues negativo amigo, no tengo otro, session de hecho destrui todo al cerrar el navegador o limpiar la cache y sigue igual.

Comment: negativo pego el link directo pruebe para que entienda un poco mejor

Comment: http://96.47.231.77/indexb25b.php?p=login

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez Revisa que no haya ningun espacio, si el archivo del error es incluido dentro de otro este tampoco puede imprimir nada antes de session_start. Algo hay seguro, pero sin ver el codigo fuente es dificil saber que

Comment: si usas anydesk avisame pero no tengo ninguna variable en _SESSION estoy 1000% seguro por que imprimi la cache de sistema y sale blanco.

Comment: web php de variables visualizar cache http://96.47.231.77/print.php

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez No se que pinta la cache aqui, el problema es que se esta enviado las cabeceras antes de que el script llege a session_strat, y esto generalmente sucece por que se ha enviado algo al navegador, un simple espacio al principio del archivo ya hara que las cabeceras se envien. Trata de localizar que es lo que se esta imprimiendo/enviando antes que de session_strat. Da igual lo que tengas en $_SESSION . Es mas, te esta diciendo donde comenzo la salida `output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\indexb25b.php:1` que puede ser ahi o  en el archivo donde se incluye.

Comment: no tienes teamview o anydesk la verdad no localizo el error

Comment: no tendra algo que ver con esto? es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245471/por-que-me-da-el-error/… por que me sale el mismo error de esa pregunta pero no veo la sintaxis de error solo veo la de post pero no existe otra alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Xerif amigo te estoy dando el código fuente de la web ¡COMPLETO! create un Index y puebelo usted mismo. No le hace falta mas nada, como sea que lo pruebe no funciona, de hecho el <?php abre en la linea de abajo sin  espacio de linea de de barra ni barra espaciadora sigue sin funcionar. ademas que lo que marcastes como posible duplicado NO sirve aun que tiene sierto parecido esto es un cangrejo de verdad. PD hice 300 web con session de apariencia el codigo parece bien escrito pero el error es evidentecuando se monta. mi whatsapp por las +584169256098 escribeme porfavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK solucion despues de partirme la cabeza hice lo que en principio subi a la primera linea el session_start(); seguia enviandome el error. el punto fue que en contre en otra web por que falle. y era colocar la codificacion **UTF-8 Sin BOM** eliminando cualquier otra codificacion en noptepad++ pestaña codificacion. quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$UserID     = $_POST['UserID'];
$Password   = $_POST['Password'];
include_once "includes/obdc_conex.php";
    if(empty($UserID))
    {
    die("<br></br><p></p><font color=red>Usuario Requerido, por favor ingrese un Usuario.</font>");
    }
        if(empty($Password))
        {
        die("<br></br><p></p><font color=red>Contrase&ntilde;a Requerida, por favor ingrese un Usuario.</font>");
        }
            $intro = "SELECT UserID FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserID = '$UserID' and Pw = '$Password'";
            $intro1 = odbc_exec($dbConn,$intro);
            if(odbc_num_rows($intro1) == 0)
            {
                die("<br></br><p></p><center><font color=red size=40>El Usuario NO Existe, Intente de Nuevo Por favor.</font><center>");
            }
                else
                {
                $_SESSION['UserID']=$UserID;
                $_SESSION['Password']=$Password;
                header('location: actionx2s.php');
                }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<!-- Mirrored from sh-Dyne.com/?p=login by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 06 May 2019 13:57:19 GMT -->
<head>
    <title>
        Iniciar Sesión | Shaiya Dyne    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Icono de la pagina web -->
            <!-- JavaScript includes - jQuery, the complexify plugin and our own script.js -->
    <!-- OpenGraph -->
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Shaiya - Dyne" >
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" >
    <meta property="og:url" content="index.php" >
    <meta property="og:title" content="Shaiya Dyne" >
    <meta property="og:image" content="img/bg.jpg" >
    <meta property="og:description" content="Sign up for the LawDynes Beta! Join to experience the gravity-based multiplayer first person shooter that shatters the laws of physics." >
    <!-- END: OpenGraph -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/ico.png" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div class="hirez-super-nav">
    <ul class="center-nav">
        <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="index0f50.php?p=home">Inicio</a>
             </li>
        <li class="nav_menu">
        Información
            <ul class="a_menu">       
                <li><a href="index6fff.php?p=rules">Reglas</a></li>
                <li><a href="index590d.php?p=drop">Drop List</a></li>
                <li><a href="index54ab.php?p=rango">Puntos por Rango</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_menu"> Ranking
            <ul class="a_menu">
                <li><a href="indexfbb8.php?p=rank">PvP Rank</a></li>
                <li><a href="index9f35.php?p=gbr">GBR Rank</a></li>
                <li><a href="index0ea0.php?p=boss">Boss Record</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
             </li>
        <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="index7b9c.php?p=donation">Donar</a>
             </li>
            <li class="a_ref">
               <a href="https://#/forms/51TaekyGsxYBg0Em1"  target="_blank">Soporte</a>
             </li>
             <li class="download">
               <a href="indexacaf.php?p=download">Descargar</a>
             </li>
             <li class="a_ref_right">
               <a href='indexb25b.php?p=login'>Iniciar Sesión</a>
             </li>
             <li class='a_ref_right'>
               <a href='indexdb34.php?p=register'>Registrarse</a>
             </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <center><a href="index0f50.php?p=home"><img src="img/logo.png" border="0" width="614" height="204"></a></center>
</div> <div class="item-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-small1">
      <div class="god-container glass horizontal"><!-- 1050 para pvp ranks, 600 para gbr, boss 700-->
      <center>
 <script src="js/login.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
<style>
    table.login_table
    {
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    table.login_table tr td:nth-child(1)
    {
        width:24px;
        text-align:right;
    }

    table.login_table tr td:nth-child(2)
    {
        width:220px;
    }

    table.login_table tr td:nth-child(3)
    {
        width:24px;
        text-align:left;
    }
</style>
<h2 class="no_select">Iniciar Sesión</h2>
<div class="text_center">
    <div class="content_360 inline_block">
        <div class="content_body">
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">
              <table class="login_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input maxlength="18" class="text_center" id="UserID" name="UserID"   placeholder="Username" type="text" value="" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input maxlength="16" class="text_center" id="Password" name="Password"  placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                            <input maxlength="16" class="text_center hidden" id="PasswordText" name="PasswordText"   placeholder="Password" type="text" value="" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="toggle_password_visibility" class="del_1" tooltip="Show password" style="vertical-align:middle;"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input name ="submit" id="button_log_in" type="submit" value="Log In" disabled="disabled" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="error"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="content_hr"></div>
                            <div>
                                <div>¿No estas registrado? <a href="indexdb34.php?p=register">Registrate aquí</a>.</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
</form>        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixfooter">
<footer>
    <div class="divline divline-top"></div>        
    <div class="footer-links">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" data-i18n="[href]site.footer.links.privacy.url;site.footer.links.privacy.copy" class="btn btn-privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" data-i18n="[href]site.footer.links.terms.url;site.footer.links.terms.copy" class="btn btn-terms">Terms of Service</a>
    </div>
    <div class="divline divline-bot"></div>
    <div data-i18n="[html]site.footer.legal" class="footer-legal">
        <span>©2016 Shaiya Dyne, Inc.</span> <span>©2016 Dyne Games, Inc.</span> <span>All Rights Reserved.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="js/accordion.js"></script>
</body>

<!-- Mirrored from /?p=login by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 06 May 2019 13:57:19 GMT -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba poniendo

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

al principio del archivo, ejemplo

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include_once "includes/obdc_conex.php";
    $UserID     = $_POST['UserID'];
    $Password   = $_POST['Password'];
    // resto del código
?>
```

> "Esta función activará el almacenamiento en búfer de la salida.
>   Mientras dicho almacenamiento esté activo, no se enviará ninguna
>   salida desde el script (aparte de cabeceras); en su lugar la salida se
>   almacenará en un búfer interno" - documentacion oficial de php

ya que al parecer imprime algo antes de session_start();

Comment: Y ese comando para qué sirve? Debes explicar cómo ayuda a resolver el problema

Comment: "Esta función activará el almacenamiento en búfer de la salida. Mientras dicho almacenamiento esté activo, no se enviará ninguna salida desde el script (aparte de cabeceras); en su lugar la salida se almacenará en un búfer interno" <- documentacion oficial de php.  ya que al parecer imprime algo antes de session_start();

Comment: Esa explicación va en la respuesta

Comment: hermano he intentado todo lo que me han dicho de hecho puse <?php session_start(); ?> y solo eso da igual mismo error necesito alguien que sepa me ayude a detectar el error

Comment: lo intente sin resultado amigo.

Comment: no tendra algo que ver con esto? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245471/por-que-me-da-el-error/245481#245481 por que me sale el mismo error de esa pregunta pero no veo la sintaxis de error solo veo la de post pero no existe otra alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Saludos Juan Carlos intenta poner <?php ob_start(); ?> arriba de   <!DOCTYPE html>